# como realizo un update masivo a una lista

Tags: sql

tengo una lista de 10.000+ filas donde tengo productos nuevos y productos que ya tengo en la DB, deseo actualizar el precio y el costo de esos productos que ya tengo en la DB con el precio y el costo que tengo en mi lista, haciendo comparaciones para verificar si el producto existe

tengo en mi lista el id, price y cost
y en la DB tengo id, price y cost.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Bienvenidx a SOes. La mejor forma de contarnos tu situación es con el código. Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añade (como texto, preferiblemente) la definición de las tablas que comentas, algunos datos de prueba, el resultado esperado sobre esos datos de prueba  y lo que has intentado hacer para resolver tu problema (las consultas, los errores).

Comment: ¿La _lista_ está en una tabla, o dónde?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción puede ser :

```
Update a 
Set A.price = b.price, A.cost=b.cost 
From db_table a left join mi_lista b 
On a.id =b.id
```

Comment: Cordial saludo, tenia una situacion similar y con este codigo pude actualizar varias tablas de forma rapida.